# How to make a user-controlled slideshow on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am teaching myself how to build webpages. In my code, I have a slideshow at the top. It automatically changes pictures. I want to change this feature so that it only changes the picture by clicking. I want arrows on both sides of the picture (previous and next buttons). How would I go about doing that? Here is my code so far: 
    HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
     <!--This header links the html and css file.-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet1.css" />
    <title>First One!</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:400,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- SCM Music Player http://scmplayer.net -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://scmplayer.net/script.js"
            data-config="{'skin':'skins/scmOrange/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':false,'shuffle':false,'repeat':1,'placement':'bottom','showplaylist':false,'playlist':[{'title':'Rigamortus','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBvngg87998'}]}"></script>
    <!-- SCM Music Player script end -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var image1 = new Image()
    image1.src = "http://the305.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/kendrick.jpg"
    var image2 = new Image()
    image2.src = "http://youheardthatnew.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/kendrick-lamar-complex-cover.jpg"
    </script>

    <img src="kendrick.jpg" name="slide" width="400" height="400" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var step = 1;
        function slideit() {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src")
            if (step<2)
                step++
            else
                step=1
            setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
        }
        slideit()
    </script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet1.css" />
    <div class="firsthalf">
        <h1>THIS IS THE WORLD OF KENDRICK LAMAR</h1>

        <!--links to music videos/drop-down-->
        <div class="menu">
            <ul><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuIUqIkDMY8"> She Needs me</a></ul>
            <ul><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLCqSMDEQsA">Swimming Pools</a></ul>
            <ul><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBvngg87998">Rigamortus</a></ul>
            <select>
                <option value="KDOT2">King</option>
                <option value="KDOT3">B/W</option>
                <option value="KDOT1">Complex</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <img src="http://api.ning.com/files/ea4x8ggFHeL55kmzdIlO2E4lRQNnC*pvkD6nlB9cwVdAgUE8IIO5hhWVrhwbRI59GfJYpxySVIplT7VWsaLTq5BqRL7-WVFG/kendrick3lr_1.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>

CSS:
body {
    font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3871f;
    text-align: center;
}

.firsthalf h1 {
    border: 5px solid black;
}

.menu ul {
    display: inline;
}

Thank you!
```

Comment: It sounds like you've answered your own question. Remove the timeout and add click methods to your next and previous buttons. Also I would recommend avoiding the use of `eval()`

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out setTimeout(); like this:

> ```
> // setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
> ```

or

> ```
> /* setTimeout("slideit()",2500); */
> ```

Statements that are oommented out won't be run. The setTimeout() statement tells your script to execute the method "slideit()" after 2500 milliseconds.

To add the clicking feature add the following to your script:

> ```
> function changeSlide(direction) { 
>     step+=direction;
>     slideit();
> }
> ```

and then from HTML make links to control the slideshow:

> ```
> <a onclick="changeSlide(-1)" href="#">go back</a>
> <a onclick="changeSlide(1)" href="#">go forward!</a>
> ```

Also in the future you should put a semi-colon at the end of each statement in your script.  You don't have to but it's good programming practice.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I recommend that you put semicolons after each javascript statement. That often solves problems.

Secondly, the way to make it slide when the user clicks a button is using the following logic:
When the user clicks back button, decrease step by 1.
When the user clicks forward button, increase step by 1.

After each of the statements above, run the slideIt() function without the timeout and the if statement. Don't forget to put an if statement before the document.images.slide.src to account for situations when step is 3 or 0.

That should make it work.